# How do I recursively work my way through a list?

Tags: r, plyr

A function call to a specific API returns a directory listing. My function call looks like this:

```
dir_listing('folder_name')
```

I am able to coerce the result to a `data.frame` and it looks like this:

```
name is_folder
foo          TRUE
bar          FALSE
```

I want to be able to add an option to my function that allows recursive listing of all subfolders and files. Something like `dir_listing('folder_name', recursive = TRUE)`

If I run `dir_listing()` on the root folder, I can subset the results that are directories using:

```
result <- dir_listing('root_folder')
folders_in_result <- subset(result, is_folder==TRUE)
```

Then I can push each name in `folders_in_result` through `dir_listing()`. Then I'd have to look at each one to see if they have any folders. What is an efficient way to acheive this operation so I can get a final `data.frame` of all files and folders searched recursively under a given folder till no more sub-folders or files are found?

EDIT: Question completely re-written for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you mean because `result[result$is_collection,]` is not really anything. If you want to pass the column to a function then just send it either the vector, `result$is_collection` or better `result[["is_collection"]]`, since that second form generalizes better to passing the argument as either a name or a value. If you want to send a row at a time then send `result[result$name=="foo",]` and `result[result$name=="bar", ]`or programmatically use `sapply` (or `lapply`) to do that:

```
sapply(row.names(result), function( x) { do_something_to( result[x, ] ) }
```

Or

```
sapply(result$name, function(x) { do_something_to( result[result$name==x, ] ) }
```

The evaluation rules for the 'plyr' package a a bit different, but in some ways more permissive ... along the lines of the rules that govern how arguments to `subset` work. But the ldply function is really a replacement for the `lapply(split( ... ))` paradigm, where the second argument is processed by the `.` function to create a split rule. Right, there is a function named `.`.

Comment: `result[result$is_collection,]` is a subset of `result` where `is_collection` is `TRUE`. I suppose I could have just written a `subset` command to avoid the confusion.